# zf2 MultiCheckbox Error: The input was not found in the haystack

Tags: zend-framework2

I am displaying a dynamic checkbox by using `Zend\Form` with this code:

```php
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox',       
    'name' => 'user_group_id',
    'attributes' =>  array(
        'id' => 'user_group_id', 
        'options' => $tagData,
    ),
));
```

This works fine. But when I have **encrypted values** in `$tagData`, the form produces this error:

> The input was not found in the haystack

I have tried `'disable_inarray_validator' => false` and `'inarrayvalidator' => false,` but none is working.

They work with `Select` element. How accomplish the same for `MultiCheckbox`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->getElement('user_group_id')->clearValidators();
```

removes all validators attached to user_group_id element

basically why are you encrypting before a field is valid?? you should do do any operation with form values only after validating all the fields .

Comment: Should we will use this on Controller , after posting form ?

Comment: Logically after posting form, but i dont know your scenario. As Haystack is matched after form is posted

Comment: @noobie-php  Well, i have try $form->getElement('user_tag_id')->clearValidators();. it is given me error "Call to undefined method User\Form\RegisterStepThree::getElement() "

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches here

1) Disable **Validators** on specific field(if ZF2 allows you to disable its validator). Tho at the moment few **Validators** after being disable remove/Hide **Haystack error**. But still you wont get form Validate.

2) You may need to **re-populate values/Reset Values** to your Field after data is posted.The thing is that ZF2 form assumes values should be in **Haystack**. For this you can do something like

```
$form->get('user_group_id')->setAttribute('option',$Request->getPost('WhateverYouAreGettingFromPostForThisCheckBox'));
```

After that Dump you Form check box element and check if the value or Option or w/e you want is set there or not.

Comment: I have tried setattribute. its not working. :(. I have try also the other answers,Its giving undefined error for disable validation

Comment: your post data that you are passing with in setAttribute is  receiving an array?

Answer (score 0):

I have this code and it seems this works for me. The form->isValid does not flag me as invalid form. 
Notice the type is equal to 'multi-checkbox'

```
// Where do you get most of your client
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => Lead::GetClients1Mapping,
            'attributes' => array('class' => ''),
            'type' => 'multi-checkbox',
            'options' => array(
                 'label' => 'Where do you get most of your clients?',
                 'value_options' => array(
                         '0' => 'Word of Mouth',
                         '1' => 'Referrals',
                         '2' => 'Yellow Pages',
                         '3' => 'Print Newspapers',
                         '4' => 'TV / Radios',
                         '5' => 'Google / Yahoo/ Bing',
                         '6' => 'Social Media / Facebook / Twitter',
                         '7' => 'Others'
                 ),),
        )); }'
```

Please make sure that you are using the multicheckbox helper to render the checkboxes in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->add(array(
           'name' => 'user_group_id',
           'type' => 'text',
           'options' => array(
               'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
               'attributes' => array(
                    'id' => 'user_id',
                    'required' => true )));
```